# SugarCRM invalid request in google maps

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM with several registered accounts.
Each of the accounts have registered billing addresses and related information that are thrown into an embedded google map as parameters and displayed under a tab called Location Map.

The embedded URL looks like this:
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyC1AkgX6WPT3_arbJZTQtLYkT_bz0rz5oQ&q={billing_address_street},
{billing_address_city}, {billing_address_postalcode}, {billing_address_country}

This works fine for some addresses but it returns an error (The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'q' parameter.) when using others.
[Link to a comparison, the second URL is invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn9Gd.png)

The second link is invalid since it has *amp;* where it isn't supposed to be. Does somebody know why this happens and how I can prevent it?

Comment: I found out that &amp; is a way to encode an ampersand (&) and it appears that in the latter case, the ampersand is not being properly parsed

Comment: If you resolved your problem, you might consider adding an answer, and marking it as accepted, or deleting your original question.

Comment: Thanks @Reisclef, I added an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we didn't know what caused this problem but we settled on solving this issue by formatting the embedded URL explicitly.